# Save Chrome Developer source edits by POSTing or PUTing to a URI?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When you are editing a `JS` or `CSS` file in Chrome developer tools you can save as a local file. You can also do this using Workspaces.

However, I would like to save the edits to a URL, using either a POST or PUT.

Does anyone know of an extension that can do this?

Ideally, whenever a change is made to a source file in the developer tools, Chrome would POST or PUT the new source of the file to the URI that the original file was requested from.

Thanks for any information, or if need be, for any tips on how to build such an extension.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you can sync your local files with server using e.g. [rsync](http://goodcode.io/blog/linux-auto-rsync/).

Comment: There's a bug requesting this feature on crbug: [crbug.com/275075](http://crbug.com/275075). Feel free to star it to receive its status updates.